# Only one vim session

Tags: session, vim

My problem is that I want to use only one vim session and
add files to that session form another terminal.
I know about gvim --remote-silent but i only use vim.
And --remote-silent doesnt work for me.

Is there any solution to this problem?
tnx in advance.

Comment: Since you've found the answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*on behalf of notphunny*:

I found the solution when I read the help...

Thing is I wasnt using `--servername` option. So right way is:

```
vim --servername Name -remote .bashrc
```

to add some files to that session

```
vim --servername Name -remote-silent .bash_history
```